# Node.js Axios package is not working in function

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

i'm using axios package for get data. my codes are not working in function. can you say me my problem ?

This code is working

```
axios.get('testurl').then(res => {
    data = res.data
}).catch(err=>{
    if(err)
        data = 0
})
console.log(data)
```

But if i use function

```
const Tsingle = url => {
    let data = null;
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
        data = res.data
    }).catch(err=>{
        if(err)
            data = 0
    })
    return data
}
console.log(Tsingle('testurl'))
```

Can i example 2 with function in ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be an async function

```
 const Tsingle = async (url) => {
     try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        console.log(response);
        return response.json()
     }  
     catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
     }
}
```

Comment: how can i edit  my code

Comment: i updated the answer try doing that

Comment: it return is null. Can you look at this photo  

https://prnt.sc/9Zt52bNGgmmp

Comment: what are you think about for codes @yagyesh

Comment: try the code like I edited above ....log the error if any and see if you can resolve it on your own first......if not then send a pic

Comment: Thank you so much. I examined your code and I found the solution to the problem